# Deeping in M2M Queries

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm

I have the following queryset which retrieves publications of the followers of the current user. `followers` is a M2M field of User to itself (many users to many users).

```
Publication.objects.filter(user__in = self.request.user.followers.all()).order_by('created')
```

As a recommendation system, I want to retrieve by a similar query the publications of followers of followers of a user, or followers of followers of followers of  [...nsteps] of him. How can I do that? The idea would be something like this:

```
Publication.objects.filter(user__in = self.request.user.followers.all().followers.followers).order_by('created')
```

If possible, a would like to not evaluate querysets or evaluate as less of them as possible for efficiency.

Comment: Yes, just query in reverse, so `Publication.objects.filter(user__follows__followers=self.request.user)` (given I understood it correctly, but it is probably better to give relevant parts of your models).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem You should write that as an answer, not as a comment.

Comment: About `user__followers__followers`, it is supposed to be a query which returns several objects (it is a many to many field), but `self.request.user` is only one object. Is the condition `user__followers__followers=self.request.user` checking if the request user is in "inside" the left many to many query? @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: @FernandoJesusGarciaHipola: yes, this acts as a JOIN, so that means you "existentially qualify" over this condition.